# Click and action generating software

Tags: windows-7, firefox, software-rec, automation

I have a plugin called selenium IDE for my firefox browser. I create some scripts using selenium to fill a web form. I wanted selenium to do run all these scripts once every hour. Unfortunately, it seems that selenium itself cannot run these scripts according to a schedule. So, I was thinking of using some other tool to click on selenium plugin and then make selenium run its scripts. Is this possible ?

I use windows 7 64 bit and firefox ver 21

Thanks.

Comment: So you're asking for a autoclicking software set to go once every hour for a infinite amount of time, correct.

Comment: @user88311 - yes thats correct.

Comment: Did my answer work as the solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Murgee autocliker.

http://www.murgee.com/auto-clicker/

It's capable of have custom intervals set, so it can click once every 5 milliseconds if you want or once a day if you want, and it can repeat endlessly.

To top it all off, it's free and there are more automation software by Murgee as well.